# How to determine if an aircraft type is currently under investigation?

Tags: aircraft-failure, accidents

The Boeing 737 flew for several years despite [rudder issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_rudder_issues) which had not been fully understood and resolved. It's conceivable that flyers who avoided the aircraft had had less probability of injury or death while flying.

How does one identify which aircraft are *currently* under some sort of investigation for similar, on-going issues?

Answer (score 3):

All aircraft are constantly under investigation. Service bulletins and airworthiness directives are issued for every certified plane and engine. These are optional and mandatory checks and maintenance to be done in additional to the normally scheduled maintenance. Every accident and important incident is investigated by the NTSB, with a [public report](http://www.ntsb.gov/aviationquery/) available online.

There is a period of time before an airworthiness directive is made final that might be considered an investigative phase, but information on this is generally not publicly available. One [notable example](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/flights/2012/11/19/airbus-rudder/1707421/) pertains to the rudder controls on the Airbus A-300.

Comment: It's worth noting (as you alluded to) that NTSB reports are a small piece of a system. A lot of information is communicated up the channel (to the FAA) through [Service Difficulty Reports](http://av-info.faa.gov/sdrx/) from mechanics and repair stations, and similarly comes back down the channel (to shops & operators) in the form of [Airworthiness Directives](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/airworthiness_directives/) and [Special Airworthiness Information Bulletins](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgSAIB.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameSet) without involving the NTSB.